# View nodejs running scripts

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

Im using nightwatch and cucumberjs to make automated tests. After the execution I send a mail report of the status of the tests, but sometimes, when the tests completes it get stuck and doesnt send the mail report. I believe there is something inside my tests that doesn't close correctly but I don't know how I can see what is still running.

How can I display a list of the current processes that are still executing?

---

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion, by processes, I mean inside my nodejs program, not windows process

Comment: linux or windows?

Comment: @AkashDathan windows

Answer (score 0):

Linux:

1. Open termial.
2. Run the `top` command.

Windows:

1. Open task manager.
2. View running processes.

Answer (score 0):

**For Linux -**

`ps -ef | grep node`

This will match all the processes with keyword node in it.

You can replace `node` with appropriate process name.

**For Windows -**

`tasklist | FIND "node"`